# What file permissions for ConfigAndLog

Tags: configandlog

What are the best file permissions for

/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/

username john, group apache

I currently have 770, but I get an error in my ssl_error_log

AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/xyz/sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.e612b0519ce870b4405c16c4.log

Shouldn't it just be apache that plugs things in, or are there are things that enter into this log file as well?

Thanks!

John

Comment: What are the permissions on the file itself?

Answer (score 2):

The files and directory need to be group writeable, and you need the which ever user that is running cron to be in that group. Check to see if cron is being run by root, that can create log files that are root only.